# primefaces filterby function gives no results

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to filter a datatable by adding the following code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{hoofdschermBean.onderzoekers}" widgetVar="onderzoekerTable" var="onderzoekeritem" rendered="#{not empty hoofdschermBean.onderzoekers}" rowStyleClass="tablerow" draggableColumns="true">
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Zoeken:" />
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('onderzoekerTable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
 </f:facet>
```

However it does not filter when I fill something in this textbox, it says no records found.
If I add filterBy on a column, only than this textbox can filter on the column variable. What am I doing wrong here?

**(P.S. I do not want to have filter functions on every separate column, that is why I wanted this facet only!)**

@Edit 14:32 27-11-2014
I have also tried to use

```
filteredValue="#{hoofdschermBean.gefilterdeOnderzoekers}"
```

and to use ViewScoped and SessionScoped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a List<> field in your managedBean so the filtered values can be saved somewhere? Also, you'd need to reference this value with a `filteredValue="#{hoofdschermBean.filtered...}"`attribute in your dataTable-Tag.

(Like in the PrimeFaces ShowCase, where they have a `List<Car> filteredCars;` in their managedBean)
Also, it might be helpful to check the scope of your ManagedBean

Comment: Yes, I have tried this:
add filteredValue="#{hoofdschermBean.gefilterdeOnderzoekers}" to the dataTable and tried to set the scope to view or sessionscope.